# How to change button size in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a dialog, and I use the below code in `OnInitDialog()`:

```
RECT rect;
((CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1))->GetWindowRect(&rect);

RECT rect2;
((CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1))->SetWindowPos(this, 
                                     rect.left, 
                                     rect.top,
                                     (rect.right-rect.left)*2,
                                     rect.bottom-rect.top, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
```

But the button's size does not change. Nothing happens. Also tried the `SWP_SHOWWINDOW` flag with the same result.

Comment: I would personally use `Cwnd::MoveWindow`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, however, consider using a `reinterpret_cast` instead of that C-Style cast.

Comment: `SWP_FRAMECHANGED` doesn't apply; you haven't changed the frame style. You should probably consider removing the casts entirely; they are not required. You are calling members that are implemented on the base class (`CWnd`).

Comment: You might also be able to use the dynamic dialog control resizing features in the IDE if appropriate.

Comment: Also note that `GetWindowRect` returns screen coordinates, whereas `SetWindowPos` specifies client coordinates. You have to call `ScreenToClient` to translate screen coordinates into client coordinates. Alternatively use flag `SWP_NOMOVE` to be able to only specify width and height, and pass 0 for X and Y.

Comment: thanks. MoveWindow works! ScreenToClient tip was useful!

Answer (score 5):

Use `MoveWindow` instead of `SetWindowPos`. Convert the coordinates by calling `ScreenToClient` after getting them by `GetWindowRect`.

Comment: Alternatively, call `SetWindowPos` with `SWP_NOMOVE`. Doing so removes the need to call `ScreenToClient`.